# Mendeley Reference Manager jumping inside the document

Tags: research-process, software, reference-managers

I am using [Mendeley Reference Manager](https://www.mendeley.com/reference-management/reference-manager) to read research papers and group them into collections.

During reading we often jump to references (such as Figures or Tables) or citations (to see the name of papers etc.). When I am reading a paper **i can't click on those hyperlinks to jump to that specific section of the article** (compared to Chrome, Edge or Zotero). Is there a setting or a way to do it that I am missing?

Read [through FAQ](https://service.elsevier.com/app/whats_new/supporthub/mendeley/) from Mendeley, but nothing mentions this. Also checked few Youtube videos explaining usage, but all of them are focusing on other aspects, but this is bothering me as can't **click on a ref** and go back with **ALT + Left arrow** like normally in programming or competing solutions like Zotero.

Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Note: I just downloaded Zotero (as a competitor app) to see if it works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted the Mendeley support for an answer to the question, as couldn't get one anywhere else. Will leave the answer for future people.

> Thank you for contacting Mendeley Support about your enquiry if there
> is a way to follow references or figures (by clicking on them) in
> Mendeley while reading a research paper?
>
> Regarding your enquiry, This feature is currently under consideration
> and will be included as part of a future update in Mendeley.
>
> Unfortunately we do not have an exact date on when it will be
> available.
>
> Rest assured that once we received an update from our product
> development team that it is now available in Mendeley, we will post it
> in our Release Notes and supporhub